# Turning off BitLocker in Windows 8 standard edition.

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, hard-drive, usb, bitlocker

I've recently upgraded my laptop from Windows 7 Professional to Windows 8 and I have a USB hard drive that everything is backed up on. When I had Windows 7 I set up BitLocker for my USB hard drive and now I want to turn it off.

I can read and write to it using the password I set up for it but because I haven't got the professional edition of Windows 8 I can't turn it off. I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows and want to use the hard drive as a backup for that as well as Windows but don't want to lose the data.

I can see two options, pay £100 to upgrade just to get BitLocker on Windows 8 or wipe the drive and start again. I don't want to do either of these so is there a third option for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the [Windows 8 Enterprise trial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) in [a VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825689.aspx) and decrypt the HDD here. After you did this, remove the Boot entry from BCD and delete the VHD.